# Como buscar a impressora padrão e imprimir texto simples em uma impressora matricial no .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, impressão

Temos uma impressora térmica que não suporta a impressão de elementos gráficos - neste caso, terei que enviar textos simples para ela.

Considerando que nosso aplicativo rodará em diversos computadores diferentes, cada um deles conectado a uma impressora distinta e que por sua vez poderão estar configuradas em portas diferentes em cada máquina (`COM1`, `COM2`, etc.), teremos que adotar a impressora padrão como destino da saída do texto a imprimir.

**Portanto:** No .NET, como posso buscar a impressora padrão e imprimir textos "crús" nela?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Para pegar a impressora padrão use a classe [`PrinterSettings`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0)<sup>(em inglês)</sup>. Exemplo:

```
var configImpressora = new PrinterSettings();
Console.WriteLine(configImpressora.PrinterName);
```

Note que desta forma você está usando o gerenciador do Windows para obter essa informação. E o que você precisa fazer para enviar os dados é justamente o oposto.

Pegar qual é a impressora padrão não vai ajudar muita coisa porque isso não garante que a impressora que está lá é adequada para o que você deseja. E mesmo que mande para ela, enviará para o gerenciador do Windows que é justamente o que você NÃO quer fazer.

Salvo eu não saber de algo sobre o assunto, duvido que essa parte te ajude em alguma coisa.

Quanto a segunda parte da pergunta:

Essencialmente você precisa escrever diretamente na porta, normalmente `PRN` ou `LPT1` ou `COM1`. mandando diretamente para a porta você evitar passar pelo gerenciador de impressão do Windows,

Exemplo simplificado (não tem a qualidade que um código em produção deveria ter):

```
var impressora = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"\\.\PRN");
impressora.Write((char)15); //inicia negrito na maioria das impressoras matriciais
impressora.Write("Teste");
impressora.Flush();
impressora.Close();
```

Quando precisei mandar para uma impressora padrão, foi basicamente isso que eu fiz.

Se você precisa escolher onde a impressora está em cada máquina, receio que você deverá que ter uma configuração local indicando onde está a impressora. Pode ser um simples arquivo de texto, mas pode ser um banco de dados local, o registro do Windows ou simplesmente permitir que o usuário escolha no momento de mandar imprimir, o que pode ser suficiente em muitos casos.

[Coloquei no **Github** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/ImpressoraMatricial.cs).

Answer (score 4):

Depois de algumas buscas, segue a forma que conseguimos fazer: Não é tão elegante (tivemos que apelar para chamadas P/Invoke<sup>1</sup>), mas funcionou muito bem.

```cs
using System.Drawing.Printing;
(...)
public void ImprimeConteudoDiretamenteNaImpressoraPadrao(string conteudo)
{
    string nomeImpressoraPadrao = (new PrinterSettings()).PrinterName;
    RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(nomeImpressoraPadrao, conteudo);
}
```

1. Método `RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter` está definido no código retirado [deste artigo](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=322091) (*Passo 8*).